# Unable to sleep execution within an api subscription callback

Tags: python, pandas, api, callback, sleep

I am making an api subscription to fetch real time live data from one of the api providers,
However i only want to pull the data every few seconds (eg 5 seconds).
I am using the below code snippet, however am unable to implement the sleep or delay effectively.
Can you please help to guide why the api is not adhering to the 5 second wait ?

```
api_ABC_connection=apiConnect(api_key="<apikey")

api_ABC_connection.ws_connect()
abc_list=[]
# Callback to receive ticks.
def on_ticks(ticks):
    print('###################')
    print(datetime.now())
    time.sleep(5)
    fetch_time_dict = {}
    fetch_time_dict['fetch_time'] = datetime.now()
    abc_list.append(fetch_time_dict)
    #print("Ticks: {}".format(ticks))
    abc_list.append(ticks)
    print(datetime.now())
    
    return abc_list
    

# Assign the callbacks.
api_ABC_connection.on_ticks = on_ticks

# subscribe stocks feeds

api_ABC_connection.subscribe_feeds(<feeds parameters>)
```

Comment: Does it need to be handled via async ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming api_ABC_connection is calling callback function asynchronously, you can try and add the `lock`. Try this, it may work:

```
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def on_ticks(ticks):
    print('###################')
    print(datetime.now())
    lock.acquire()
    time.sleep(5)
    lock.release()
    fetch_time_dict = {}
    fetch_time_dict['fetch_time'] = datetime.now()
    abc_list.append(fetch_time_dict)
    #print("Ticks: {}".format(ticks))
    abc_list.append(ticks)
    print(datetime.now())
    
    return abc_list
```

You may want to put both `acquire()` and `release()` methods into another place. It depends on what behavior you actually expect.